# VB Evaluate two integers with a list

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to evaluate two integers separated with values of list of two integers.

[image]

For example:

i receive two integers from two variables

> id1 = 1
>
> id2 = 2

Then i have a list of two integers

> 1 - 2
>
> 4 - 6

I want to check if that ids are in the list of integers together. Since we cannot do

```
For e = 0 To excluidos.Count
    If misGallos(i).taquillaP = excluidos(e).id1P Or excluidos(e).id2P And _
       misGallos(j).taquillaP = excluidos(e).id1P Or excluidos(e).id2P Then

        MsgBox("igua")
    End If
Next e
```

I dont know whats the better way to do it. If i should put those ids in another list to compare both list or if exist any method to put those ids together and check if there are equals on the list.

Comment: If list.Contains(id1) AndAlso list.Contains(id2) Then...

Comment: @soohoonigan but i need to compare them together because in the list i have two integers per row and that if compare that two ids separated

Comment: Explain how exactly do you need them compared.

Comment: @CruleD the list is built of two integers each row, and i receive two ids separated, i need to check if those ids together are in the list. I dont know if its better to add those ids in another list or if exist any method to concatenate both ids to compare in list

Comment: Two IDs ok, do you need to check if either ID is in both lists or just if IDs are in same row on two lists?

Comment: @CruleD I need to check if two ids are in one row of the list, like in the image i post, id1 = 1 and id2=2 those ids together are in the first row of the list

Comment: Does ID#1 only check List#1 or both?

Comment: @CruleD both, because i dont know if id1 will be in first column or in the second same with id2. Need to see if id1 and id2 are in one row of the list, independient of wich columns are they

Comment: Can same number be in both columns (on same row)?

Comment: @CruleD no, they will be always different

Comment: Then the quickest is to simply check if ID#1 is contained in either list, if so then check for other id in the other list at same index.

Comment: @CruleD i edited the post to what i do bases of your answer but it doesnt work correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your logic is wrong, try something like this:

```
    Dim List1 As New List(Of Integer) From {1, 3, 5, 22}
    Dim List2 As New List(Of Integer) From {2, 4, 8, 12}
    Dim ID1 As Integer = 22
    Dim ID2 As Integer = 12

    If List1.Contains(ID1) Then

        If List2.Contains(ID2) AndAlso List2(List1.IndexOf(ID1)) = ID2 Then 'is present on list and same row
            Debug.Print("hi1")
        End If

    ElseIf List2.Contains(ID1) Then

        If List1.Contains(ID2) AndAlso List1(List2.IndexOf(ID1)) = ID2 Then 'is present on list and same row
            Debug.Print("hi2")
        End If

    End If
```